# jest and jasmine in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, jestjs

I've effectively replaced karma/jasmine with jest in an angular project and the tests are running great....but:

I didn't remove jasmine (protractor needs it) and now I'm running into the issue that if I use `spyOn` instead of `jest.spyOn` in my spec files, it uses the jasmine spy and not the jest one (which are implemented differently). This is a gross developer experience and I'd like to just remove jasmine completely from my unit tests, but I have no idea how.

How can I set up my tsconfig.spec.json to exclude jasmine during compilation of my spec files?

I'm using `jest-preset-angular` which uses `ts-jest`.

If I haven't included enough information, please feel free to bug me for more!

This is my `tsconfig.spec.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": ""
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "public",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types" <-- jasmine types are in here too!
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015"
  }
}
```

My jest config tells `ts-jest` to use my `tsconfig.spec.json` file like this:

```
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      ...
      "tsConfig": "<rootDir>/public/tsconfig.spec.json" <-- here!
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jest` is based on `Jasmine` and [includes a "light" version](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/jasmineLight.ts)...

...so `spyOn` [exists in the `Jest` source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4d3c1a187bd429fd8611f6b0f19e4aa486fa2a85/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/spyRegistry.ts#L79).

---

It is deprecated and undocumented, but as you have found it still works to call it.

It is likely to be removed completely in a future version of `Jest` (the legacy `Jasmine` pieces are gradually being removed).

---

To help track down calls to `spyOn` you can use the [`errorOnDeprecated`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#errorondeprecated-boolean) CLI option.

Launch `Jest` like this:

`jest --errorOnDeprecated`

...and you will see an error logged any time `spyOn` is called in your tests.